# Html-Select-Tag-How to convert string value into javascript without using eval()?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I've read in some post that is not a good practice to use **eval()** method in JavaScript. So I would like to find a way to obtain the same value on *selectedColorValue* without using **eval()** and be able to manipulate this value. 
I've tried with

const selectedColorValue = color.options[color.selectedIndex]; but any success.

HTML

```
<select name="" id="color">
     <option value="blue">blue</option>
     <option value="red">red</option>
     <option value="green">green</option>
</select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 const color = document.getElementById('color');

 //const selectedColorValue = eval(color.value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your eval is unnecessary, simply just retrieve the `value` attribute from the element itself, and it will return it to the variable `color`.

```
const color = document.getElementById('color').value;
```

Or if you prefer to keep the element as a variable:

```
const color = document.getElementById('color'); 
const selectedColorValue = color.value;  //No need for eval
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a `.value` on your script like so:

Please click on the `Run code snippet` blue button below.

```js
function getValue()
{

const color = document.getElementById('color').value;
console.log(color);

}
```

```html
<select name="" id="color" onchange='getValue()'>
     <option value="blue">blue</option>
     <option value="red">red</option>
     <option value="green">green</option>
</select>
```